# Web.py does not work properly when started on boot (OpenWrt)

Tags: python, web.py, openwrt, init.d

I'm using `python` to run a small webservice on an `OpenWrt` board.
The script is based on web.py and works perfectly when started from command line, but in order to start automatically it is configured to run from init.d like

```
/usr/bin/python /www2/webservice/lightcontrol.py 8081 &
```

In this case it shows no errors on start, but it just does not respond on HTTP requests, although it should be listening on port 8081:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Any ideas how to track down what is missing  / different on start?

Comment: There's a difference when you start the script in a `user` session and the machine starts a script in a `system` session. Can you post the error messages and code?

Comment: No error messages :(  That's the problem

Comment: more details about your starting script (`lightcontrol.py`)?

Comment: We tried to trace down where the problem is located and it looks like 

/web/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py  - > HTTPRequest.respond() is called but nothing happens - response is not delivered to client